# How to correctly predict target variables with sklearn regressor in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series

I want to predict future prices from the marketing time series data. To do so, I use `sklearn` for my task because it is more flexible than `statsmodel` and `fbprophet`. However, for preprocessing, I removed seasonality from time-series data by taking logarithmic values for both selected features and targeted variables, then use log values and lag values to make predictions. What I don't understand is how each individual feature (it has lag value and log value) contribute to predicting target variables. In the prediction problem, first, we normalize and preprocess the features, then selectively choose the features by its features importance to reduce dims of training data, then train the model and get the corresponding prediction.

**new update**

In a time-series setting, however, we need to tackle seasonality first, then use log value and lag values of the features to make predictions. In my attempt, I just simplify the process by not using many features (didn't use feature importance), just selected two features, and try to predict target variables (where each feature has its log values and lag values in order to remove seasonality). why my way of predicting the target variable is not efficient? what would be the better approach to do this? Can anyone point me out any possible suggestions or coding remedy?

thanks to @smci who encouraged me to specify the question and focus on one problem only in my post. I did specify the data source link and used time-series data as follow:

time-series data was taken from http://statistics.mla.com.au/Report/List which is a market information statistical database. I shared the [reproducible data in this link](https://gofile.io/d/aDb7pS) and I shared my full coding attempt in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/adamFlyn/8c8d147d4b23f8234d86dd18f224cdb2)

**my attempt**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor

url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/f71e2e0e66303df23dfc2f37ec98e8c7/raw/ba9e871e90201eb504e30127e99cf6179c3e3b18/tradedf.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['dates'])
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

df['log_eyci'] = np.log(df.eyci)  ### Log value
df['log_aus_avg_rain'] = np.log(df['aus_avg_rain'])  ### Log value

for i in range(3):
    df[f'avgRain_lag_{i+1}'] = df['aus_avg_rain'].shift(i+1)   
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    df[f'log_avgRain_lag_{i+1}'] = np.log(df[f'avgRain_lag_{i+1}'])
    
for i in range(3):
    df[f'eyci_lag_{i+1}'] = df.eyci.shift(i+1)   
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    df[f'log_eyci_lag_{i+1}'] = np.log(df[f'eyci_lag_{i+1}'])
    df[f'log_difference_{i+1}'] = df.log_eyci - df[f'log_eyci_lag_{i+1}']

X,Y = df[['log_difference_2', 'log_difference_3', 'aus_avg_rain', 'aus_slg_fmCatl']] , df['log_difference_1']
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False, random_state=42)
```

**fit the model with AdaBoost Regressor**

```
mdl_adaboost = AdaBoostRegressor(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=0.01)
mdl_adaboost.fit(X_train, Y_train)   # Fit the data
pred = mdl_adaboost.predict(X_test)  # make predictions
```

when I tried to make a plot for prediction output, I tried below

```
## make plot
test_size = X_test.shape[0]
plt.plot(list(range(test_size)), np.exp(df.tail(test_size).log_eyci_lag_1  + pred), label='predicted', color='red')
plt.plot(list(range(test_size)), df.tail(test_size).eyci, label='real', color='blue')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title('Predicted vs Real with log difference values')
```

@smci pointed out that using `train, test = X[0:size], X[size:len(X)]` is not good idea. I am wondering how should I correct the limitation of my approach.

The one problem I am asking in this question, how to predict target variables from time-series data which might have seasonality. I did use log and lag values for features and target variables. Now I am little lost how do I use those for prediction, and how those might or might not contribute to predict target variables.

**intuition behind this**

I developed my intuition to predict commodity prices from [this site](https://www.mla.com.au/Prices-markets#), so far, my way of modeling this task remains problematic. I thank @smci to bring up [this source](https://www.agric.wa.gov.au/newsletters/wabc/western-australian-beef-commentary-issue-13?page=0%2C2) as well. Can anyone suggest a possible coding remedy or the right way to make this type of prediction in `scikit-learn`? Any idea?

**new update: objective**:

I used the Australian market information database, what I am trying to do is predict Australian beef price, like [this site shows](https://www.mla.com.au/Prices-markets#). Historical marketing prices data is from the Australian marketing information database, and I am going to forecast Australian beef price by taking simple features (like cattle slaughter number, cattle production, and so on). Since I am using monthly data, I think taking monthly seasonality would be fine. Again thanks a lot to @smci for pushing me to clarify my post and his helpful feedback.

Comment: What you're talking about is "how to interprete the model", not "how to correctly predict", I guess. Different, even black box, models have diferent ways of interpreting models, including assessment of which features affect result and how much.

Comment: You already fitted your model, you already applied predict method on it, what is your problem?

Comment: 1. Predicting furture is most difficult type of prediction and not always successul. 2. Most sklearn predictors, and boosters and baggers, do not predict several steps in advance, they do it one step at a time. 3. To predict several steps you need to switch to either a loop and further predict on one step prediction you already done, or switch to ARIMA models available either in `R` `forecast` package or `statsmodels` for Python

Comment: An attempt definitely can be made, but only one step ahead (this is how most of ML time series problems structured), or, if your time series conform to ARIMA, you may try predicting any number periods in the future at once. It's not a matter of plot, it's how algos are supposed to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222865/discussion-between-adam-and-sergey-bushmanov).

Comment: isn't a nn an easier solution?

Comment: We know nothing about which dataset you're using, what trends it has, what time-period it represents. In your question, can you edit a link to the dataset? and show a plot with several historical traces. Also, `train, test = X[0:size], X[size:len(X)]` is an awful way to featurize a timeseries (even if we assume it's in chronological order). You have to **use rolling-window to generate multiple train-and test set splits for the same input**.

Comment: Ok it would help if you added the original citation for that dataset (what is it, where did it come from, what do the columns mean?). It's a monthly timeseries over 2015-01 ... 2020-08. Upon googling, I find it's [Australian (wholesale) beef prices](https://www.agric.wa.gov.au/newsletters/wabc/western-australian-beef-commentary-issue-13?page=0%2C2). So I expect there will be both annual seasonality, also longer-term economic supply-and-demand fluctuations, dependence on Aus and foreign economy, weather crises, tariffs, trade wars etc etc. A lot of those are extrinsic to the historical values.

Comment: @smci I explained column in discussion chat, and target varialble `eyci`, please see [this](https://www.mla.com.au/prices-markets/market-news/2020/return-of-the-eyci/). I tried [my attempt with statsmodel](https://gist.github.com/adamFlyn/8c8d147d4b23f8234d86dd18f224cdb2) but neither of them make much sense to me

Comment: Adam: [SO rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) require you to **edit all the missing information into the actual question**. (Forget chat, it's not linked or indexed to this question, it's ephemeral, it will go away, comment links here to chat will get deleted someday.) So please click Edit on the question above and do that. You still haven't told us are we trying to predict Australian or US prices! Mamma mia!

Comment: @smci I updated my post with specifying data sources and showing full coding attempts and data that I used. Would you mind to give me possible thoughts to refine my current approach? Could you able to update your attached solution? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @smci could you update your answer before assigning a bounty score and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly offtopic to SO and very broad, you're asking multiple questions spanning [DataScience.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), **how to use detrending, which type of model to use, how to use rolling-window technique on a single timeseries dataset to generate multiple (train, test) slices**, where to get monthly datasets for the extrinsic variables below:

- Your dataset (please add citation) is monthly (wholesale) USDA beef prices over 2015-01 ... 2020-08. Are these prices from Australia (https://www.agric.wa.gov.au/newsletters/wabc/western-australian-beef-commentary-issue-13?page=0%2C2), or the US? (Please add citation, data dictionary to explain columns, etc.). It's good to develop an intuition for what you're trying to model, not just throw more data and more complex models at it.
- and you want to predict future prices for 12-18mths: `2020-09 .. 2022-02`
- So I expect there will be both:

  - annual seasonality
  - longer-term economic supply-and-demand fluctuations

    - dependence on US(?)/Aus economy
    - dependence on whichever foreign economies US(?)/Aus exports each particular type of beef to (China, Japan, Korea et al.)
  - other extrinsic events (recessions, weather crises, tariffs, subsidies, US soybean trade wars, etc.) which simply can't be predicted from the historical beef price values (and if you throw more historical datasets at it, or go further back in time, you'll only clog up your model without adding predictive power for the future).
- so if you want more accuracy you really you want a macromodel of all these extrinsic things - not just the raw historical dataset values themselves.